# IOS Swift- App does not open specific selected tab bar controller index when push notification is received

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller

My app has 5 tab bar and each time i receive push notification i would like the app to navigate to 3rd tab in the index. I able to achieve it when the app is in foreground or background (in active state). if the app is closed and i try to open the push notification the app opens and crashes.
Below is the code which i have

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    let tabbar:UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tabbar.selectedIndex = 3
}
```

Kindly let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below code in the end of `diFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
 if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            _ = notification["aps"] as! [String : AnyObject]

            (window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedIndex = 3
        }
```

Comment: i receive the following error when i added at the end of diFinishLaunchingWithOptions
**Use of undeclared type 'UITabbarController'**

Comment: Sorry, a typing mistake. It should be `TabBar` with a capital B.

Comment: this is the exact code which i have still the same error 
        `if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            _ = notification["aps"] as! [String : AnyObject]

             (window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController).setSelectIndex = 3
        }`
**AppDelegate.swift:96:42: Value of type 'UITabBarController' has no member 'setSelectIndex' **

Comment: Change `setSelectIndex` to `selectedIndex`.

Comment: Happy to help .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you debugging your code? If the app crashes there, it can very possibly be that the window.rootViewController is not a UITabBarController.

You can either debug that or change the as! in as?
And:

```
tabbar?.selectedIndex = 3
```

If the app doesn't crash, your tab bar controller is somewhere else. Just find it.

Also remember to check for your notification in the options dictionary.

Comment: you were right about the disconnected tabbar controller. i had to add a delay in order to make the code work. Thank you

Comment: @AlessandroRanaldi how have u done that could u post beacuse my app als crashed

Comment: Dilip, What exactly are you trying to do?